# how to display company name instead of email address while sending password reset email in django

Tags: django

how to display name instead of email address.I am using PasswordResetView and i have configured this email in settings.py.When i just use only email address in EMAIL_HOST_USER then it works fine but after i changed like this to display name then it is not working.How can i solve this

> settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "CompanyName <company@gmail.com>"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
```

> urls.py

```
path('password-reset/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='students/password_reset.html',
                                              email_template_name='students/password_reset_email.html',
                                              success_url=reverse_lazy('students:password_reset_done')),
         name='password_reset'),
    path('password-reset/done/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='students/password_reset_done.html'),
         name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='students/password_reset_confirm.html',
                                                     success_url=reverse_lazy('students:password_reset_complete')
                                                     ), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password-reset-complete/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='students/password_reset_complete.html'),
         name='password_reset_complete'),
```

Comment: can you show where you are using the `PasswordResetView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the **`from_email`** argument in the **`as_view()`** from the url config itself.

```
path('password-reset/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='students/password_reset.html',
                                              email_template_name='students/password_reset_email.html',
                                              success_url=reverse_lazy('students:password_reset_done',),
                                              from_email="CompanyName <company@gmail.com>"),
         name='password_reset'),
```

The **`EMAIL_HOST_USER`** settings has no role in this context. So, change it back to the original state.